# Generic points and local entropies

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

Let $X=\{1,\dots,p\}^\mathbb{N}$ be the space of sequences on a finite alphabet with a metric inducing the product topology, and let $\sigma\colon X\to X$ be the shift map.  Let $\mu$ be a $\sigma$-invariant Borel probability measure on $X$.

A point $x\in X$ is *generic* for $\mu$ if $\frac 1n S_n\phi(x) \to \int \phi\\,d\mu$ for every $\phi\in C(X)$, where $S_n \phi(x) = \phi(x) + \phi(\sigma x) + \cdots + \phi(\sigma^{n-1}x)$.  Denote by $G_\mu$ the set of $\mu$-generic points.

**Fact #1.**  If $\mu$ is ergodic, then Birkhoff's ergodic theorem implies that $\mu(G_\mu)=1$.

---

The *local entropy* of a point $x\in X$ is $h_\mu(x) = \lim_{n\to\infty} -\frac 1n \log \mu([x_1\dots x_n])$, where $[x_1 \dots x_n] = \{ y\in X \mid y_i = x_i \\,\forall 1\leq i\leq n\}$, provided the limit exists.  Denote by $Z_\mu$ the set of points $x$ for which $h_\mu(x)$ exists and is equal to the measure-theoretic entropy $h_\mu(\sigma)$.

**Fact #2.**  If $\mu$ is ergodic, then Shannon-McMillan-Breiman implies that $\mu(Z_\mu)=1$.

---

The measure $\mu$ is a Gibbs measure if there exists a function $\phi\in C(X)$ and constants $K,P>0$ such that
$$
K^{-1} \leq \frac{\mu([x_1\dots x_n])}{e^{-nP + S_n \phi(x)}} \leq K
$$
for every $x\in X$ and $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

**Fact #3.**  If $\mu$ is a Gibbs measure, then $G_\mu \subset Z_\mu$.  That is, the local entropy of a point $x$ with respect to $\mu$ is "what it should be" provided the Birkhoff averages of continuous functions along the orbit of $x$ are "what they should be".

(Actually, even more is true:  for a Gibbs measure the local entropy $h_\mu(x)$ of any point $x$ is completely determined by the Birkhoff averages $\frac 1n S_n \phi(x)$ of a single function.)

---

**Question.**  What is the broadest class of measures for which the inclusion $G_\mu \subset Z_\mu$ holds -- that is, for which genericity for Birkhoff averages of continuous functions implies genericity for local entropies?  Does this hold for *all* ergodic measures?  If it does not, is there a natural class of measures beyond the Gibbs measures (and various notions of weak Gibbs measures) for which it does hold?

**Related question.**  Gibbs measures (and weak Gibbs measures) have the property that there exists a function $\phi\in C(X)$ such that $h_\mu(x)$ is completely determined by $\frac 1n S_n \phi(x)$ for *every* $x\in X$.  (Not just for a full measure set of $x$ -- this is true for all ergodic measures.)  Is there an example of a measure $\mu$ such that there is no single function $\phi\in C(X)$ whose Birkhoff averages determine $h_\mu(x)$, but there exist *two* function $\phi_1, \phi_2\in C(X)$ such that $h_\mu(x)$ is completely determined by $\frac 1n S_n \phi_i(x)$ for $i=1,2$?

Comment: Hi Vaughn, in the Fact #1 the measure theoretic entropy is it not $h_{\mu}(\sigma)$ ?

Comment: @Leandro:  You're right, of course.  I'll edit it.

Answer (score 4):

My feeling is that there exists an ergodic measure $\mu$ for which $G_\mu \setminus Z_\mu$ is nonempty. It is sufficient to find a uniquely ergodic subsystem which admits exceptional points for the Shannon-McMillan-Breiman theorem. I think that one can be constructed symbolically without too much difficulty by the following method.

Pick a real number $h$ lying strictly between 0 and $\log 2$, and consider a sequence $x$ in the 2-shift with the following properties:

1) For every $n \geq 1$, the sequence contains precisely $e^{nh + o(n)}$ distinct words of length $n$. (For reasons of subadditivity the $o(n)$ term is necessarily positive).

2) Every word which occurs in $x$ occurs with a well-defined frequency which is not equal to 0 or 1.

The orbit closure $X$ of such a sequence is then a uniquely ergodic subsystem of the shift with topological entropy equal to $h$. An explicit procedure for constructing such a sequence was given by Grillenberger in the 1970s (in my opinion it's not particularly hard). In particular, $X$ supports a unique invariant measure $\mu$ and $G_\mu$ includes the whole of $X$. Now, suppose that the word $x$ also satisfies the property:

3) There exists a nested sequence of subwords of $x$ such that the frequency of each of these words is less than $e^{-n(h+\varepsilon)}$ for some $\varepsilon>0$.

This implies that there is a nested sequence of cylinder sets in $X$, containing some point, such that the measures of these cylinder sets decrease at a rate faster than the "standard" local entropy $h$, and hence the point in the intersection of the cylinders belongs to $G_\mu$ but not to $Z_\mu$.

I think that there shouldn't be any problem in reconciling all three of these criteria with one another, but I will admit that I haven't attempted to write a proof of that. I think it sounds reasonable that for a larger class of measures than Gibbs measures we should have $G_\mu \subseteq Z_\mu$, but I don't have much to contribute to that end of the question...